# how can I draw /redraw a line from main view into subview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to draw as well as redraw some lines from view into my sub-view say I have big view and I want to draw a line inside my mySubView.
I know by the help of drawrect event I can draw some line but this event calls only once at the starting of the program actually I want to put some button and then draw my lines and stuffs like that whenever I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your buttonPush action handler, call the `setNeedsDisplay`, it will mark the view's entire bounds rectangle as needing to be redrawn ( thus , your `drawRect:` will be executed )

```
-(IBAction)buttonPush:(UIButton *)sender
{
    ...
    [mySubView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```